# How can I see if a date is on a weekend?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table:

```
 ID | Name | TDate
 1  | John | 1 May 2013, 8:67AM
 2  | Jack | 2 May 2013, 6:43AM
 3  | Adam | 3 May 2013, 9:53AM
 4  | Max  | 4 May 2013, 2:13AM
 5  | Leny | 5 May 2013, 5:33AM
```

I need a query that will return all the items where `TDate` is a weekend. How would I write such a 
query?

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR**

```
select 
  table.*,
  EXTRACT (DAY FROM table.tdate )
from table
```

I did a select using EXTRACT to just see if I can get the right values. However, EXTRACT with the parameter DAY returns the day of the month. If I instead use WEEKDAY, as per the documentation [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-extract.html), then I get error:

```
ERROR: timestamp units "weekday" not recognized
SQL state: 22023
```

limit 1250

**EDIT**
TDate has a data type of datetime (timestamp). I just wrote it like that for easy reading. But regardless of the type, I could easily cast between types if need be.

I know dates 4May and 5May are weekends (as they fall on a Saturday and a Sunday). Does firebird allow for a way to write a query that will return dates if they fall on weekends.

Comment: wat time is this `1 May 2013, 867AM`? what is the data type of `TDATE`?

Comment: Please always show your efforts while asking questions.

Comment: what sql? MySQL? Oracle? or SQL Server?

Comment: I fixed my spelling mistake and added an edit with more info. And hims056, I think I did more than adequate effort with my question. Take the attitude elsewhere please.

Comment: @coderama - What effort did you do? Show what have you tried?

Comment: Guess you could find some ideas here: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html

Comment: I made effort when typing the question. I am busy trying to find SQL that will return this data. As soon as I have something, I will post it here. Again, attitude is not necessary.

Comment: p.s. i'm trying to find something that works using "extract"

Comment: @coderama - Attitude? What attitude? I asked you politely using *Please*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT ID, Name, TDate
FROM your_table
WHERE EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM TDate) IN (6,0)
```

**UPDATE**

condition must be `(0,6)` not `(0,1)`.

Comment: This is helping. I'm updating my question with the firebird equivelant, but it's still moaning.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: For Firebird the exact [syntax](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-extract.html) is `EXTRACT(WEEKDAY FROM TDate)`

Comment: Weekday was the right keyword! I checked the code and this function was connecting to a POstGres database, and not the FireBird database as I anticipated. The above code works for firebird. *facepalm*